# Laravel Eloquent not returning join table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following function that joins 2 models.

```
$listing = Game::where('status', '2')->whereHas('transaction', function ($query) use($id) {
    $query->where('status',1)->where('transaction_id', Crypt::decrypt($id));
})->get();
```

I have a **Game** model that has the following code.

```
protected $table = 'game_listings';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
protected $fillable = ['user_id','asset_id','trade_id','market_name','name','picture','description','price','status','clicks'];
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RELATIONS
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}

public function transaction()
{
     return $this->hasOne('App\Models\GameTransaction','listing_id','id');
}
```

I also have a **GameTransaction** model that has the following code.

```
protected $table = 'game_transactions';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
protected $fillable = ['listing_id', 'transaction_id', 'payee_id'];
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

The problem I'm having is the `$listing` variable is only returning data from the `game_listings` table, and nothing from the `game_transactions` table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`whereHas` doesn't load relations. You should use `with` for this. Try:

```
   Game::where('status', '2')->whereHas('transaction', function ($query) use($id) {
    $query->where('status',1)->where('transaction_id', Crypt::decrypt($id));
})->with('transaction')->get()
```

Comment: @Curtis no problem